# Number of active threads keeps increasing

Tags: android, multithreading

I am using executorService to excecute only one task at a time using this code

```
executorService=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

And I am using `Thread.activeCount()` to get the number of active threads, but whenever I submit a runnable task to the executorService the number of active threads is incremented by one. How is that possible?

I thought `newSingleThreadExecutor()` allows executing only one task at a time. Why does the number of threads keep increasing? Shouldn't the number of threads only increase by one and not more?

Note that I am also using `future` to cancel execution of all runnables before even submitting a new task and it works fine; all runnables are interrupted. However, the number of active threads keeps increasing.

Edit:  This is the code that gets called whenever I press on a button (`Worker` is just a class that implements runnable):

```
private void handle() {
    executorService=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Worker worker=new Worker();
    future=executorService.submit(new Worker());
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297989/6028746

Comment: oh you mean i should only call this code executorService=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` only once ?

Comment: No, but maybe  the framework initiate new reference when you call it again

Comment: but i don't understand why the active threads keeps increasing

Comment: It's not normal but i can't tell you why it's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call it it cretes a new Executor.  Each single threaded executor has its own thread.  If you want to do multiple jobs on that executor you call newSingleThreadedExecutor once and submit all the jobs to that executor.  You do not call newSingleThreadedExecutor multiple times

Comment: if i do that ,only the first task submitted to the executor works ,if i submit another task it doesn't work anymore even though the first task is completed

Comment: oops your right ,i have been trying to solve this for like 10 hours ,it seems that my task never actually finish because i was calling Looper.loop at the end of run method

Comment: THat makes sense.  If you call Looper.loop(), it will wait for new messages forever, thus never actually exit the task.  Which means any other tasks you schedule never get run.

Comment: yes my phone was actually get overheating as well it seems that i have been running like a 100 thread without even knowing :) ,thx